# Circle segments with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a circle segment with TikZ from the point `(340:1)` to `(200:1)` in positive direction, that means the longer of the two possible segments.

I have tried a lot, everythink in the form

```
\draw (340:1) arc (340:200:1)
```

but I never got what I want.
What are the right parameters?

Comment: Try `\draw (340:1) arc (340:200+360:1)` or `\draw (340:1) arc (340-360:200:1)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
\draw (340:1) arc (340:200+360:1)
```

or:

```
\draw (340:1) arc (340-360:200:1).
```

Comment: Could you explain what each of the numbers mean?

Comment: @usernumber `(304:1)` is (_angle_ : _distance_) for a coordinate (polar coordinate). `(340:200+360:1)` is ( _start angle_ : _end angle_ : _radius_ ) for an arc.